# How to disable iChat

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, ichat

In the past, I used iChat + Chax for instant messaging on my Show Leopard. Then I switched to Adium but iChat seems to be started automatically though I removed it from login items.

```
ps ax | grep iChat
  188   ??  S      1:21.91 /System/Library/Frameworks/IMCore.framework/iChatAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/iChatAgent -psn_0_94231
67977   ??  S      0:00.31 /System/Library/Frameworks/IMCore.framework/iChatAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/iChatAgent -psn_0_29355005
```

Why iChatAgent is still started? How to completely disable it?

Thanks

Comment: I have the feeling this has something to do with FaceTime maybe? At least I think FaceTime starts automatically and uses iChat in the background.

Comment: @slhck: I don't think so. At least on my system (10.6.7), iChat or iChatAgent don't show up on the process list when using FaceTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you also removed the iChat Menu Extra that looks like a speech bubble by `Command-dragging` it from the menubar. Activating this menu item does launch the `iChatAgent`. Alternatively, disable it in iChat's preferences:

[image]

You might need to log out and back in for `iChatAgent` to quit, or just `kill` it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems working. Pretty strange behavior.